# ajax post return 405 (Method Not Allowed) on Laravel 5.7

Tags: ajax, laravel

Hello :) I have a register form and send Ajax post data to controller but console return **405** error . Below is my code:

**Javascript code:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.btn-register').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var post = $('#register_form').serialize();
        console.log(post);
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url :'/user/register/',
            data : post,
            success : function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    })
})
```

**Routes** `web.php`:

```
## User Section ##
Route::group(['prefix'=>'user'],function (){

    Route::post('register',function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
        return $request;
    });

    # User MiddleWare
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'user'],function (){

    });
});
```

**My register form:**

```
<form method="post" action="/user/register" id="register_form">
    <div class="form-group text-right">

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-left" name="email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-right">

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" name="name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-right">

        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control text-left" name="password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-register" value="reg">
    </div>
</form>
```

Post update and register form added . I tested this form normally and without Ajax work good and do not problem . but when I use `$.ajax` or `$.post` error return !!!

Comment: Can you share the code of the `#register_form`?

Comment: question update !

Comment: you need pass token in your ajax

Comment: remove the trailing slash at the end of the url in the $.ajax() call `url :'/user/register/',`

Comment: thanks @simonecosci this work like charm :)

Comment: never use trailing slash in the end of the url in ajax call. i'm glad that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @simonecosci . change Ajax url work :

```
url :'/user/register/'
```

to

```
url :'/user/register'
```

Answer (score 0):

found error in your javascript code

```
$(function () {
    $('.btn-register').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var post = $('#register_form').serialize();
        console.log(post);
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
                url :'/user/register',
            data : post,
            success : function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {//add this also so you can get error if uccers
                 console.log(error);
            }
        });
    })
});
```